# Creating an empty jQuery object: $({}) or $()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen the following two variable initializations to create an empty jQuery object. Is there a major difference or advantage to use one over the other?

```
var a = $({});
var b = $();
```

Comment: I think I've seen `$([])` too. Maybe I'm mistaken though...

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: yes, I have seen $([]) as well. To be clear, it is $({}) I indeed am asking about. e.g (https://gist.github.com/661855)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you meant `$([])`, that's something from the old days where calling `$()` was actually equivalent to `$(document)` (which was an undocumented feature).  So to get an empty set, you'd have to call `$([])`.  This was [changed in jQuery 1.4](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#returning-empty-set); the documented functionality of `$()` is now to return an empty set.

Passing *objects* to the jQuery constructor is an entirely different beast.  `$({})` doesn't create an empty jQuery object.  It creates a jQuery object with a length of 1; the selected item is the object itself.

Passing JS objects to the jQuery constructor lets you take advantage of a more esoteric feature of jQuery: binding and triggering events on (non-DOM) objects.

For example:

```
var obj = { some: 'stuff' };

$(obj).on('someevent', function() { ... });

$(obj).trigger('someevent');
```

**Either way**, if your goal is to instantiate a new, empty jQuery object, use `$()`.

Comment: `Passing JS objects to the jQuery constructor lets you take advantage of a more esoteric feature of jQuery: binding and triggering events on (non-DOM) objects.` why does doing  `$({})` help with binding and triggering events?

Comment: It gives you a jquery object which you can listen for/trigger arbitrary events on.

Comment: thanks for you response. so in your answer you say the selected item is a just a made up empty object (`{}` inside `$()`) . I've been seeing that for pub/subs https://gist.github.com/cowboy/661855. 
why do they use this empty object?  could they just use a random element $(.element) instead. Im sorry that I am confused. working with an empty object is good for event emitting? Im new to pub/sub. why is `$({})` good for pub/sub? please answer. thanks

Comment: nothing ever gets put into the empty object.I'ts just there to handle events?

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean:

```
var a = $([]); //<- array not object
var b = $();
```

No advantage that I know of, the first one is the old version, since 1.4 you can use the later.