# Events on empty jquery objects

Tags: jquery

What is the use of empty jquery object here? And what does it mean when we have an event like `on`/`off` on an empty object.

```
(function($) {

  var o = $({}); //<--

  $.subscribe = function() {
    o.on.apply(o, arguments);
  };

  $.unsubscribe = function() {
    o.off.apply(o, arguments);
  };

  $.publish = function() {
    o.trigger.apply(o, arguments);
  };

}(jQuery));
```

Code from [***here***](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/661855)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an empty jQuery object: $({}) or $()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149945/creating-an-empty-jquery-object-or)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var o = $({});
```

jQuery allows you to select an empty object which will return it wrapped with all the extra jQuery sugar, ie. triggering and event listening. So you can then trigger and listen for events on this empty (jQuery) object.